# Set user and PAT so I don't ever have to enter it again?

Tags: git, github

How do I set the user and PAT ([Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)) on a cloned github so that I never have to type them in again?

Comment: Q: Did `git config --global credential.helper cache` work?  Q: What Git client are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> [Using Personal Access Tokens with Git and GitHub](https://www.edgoad.com/2021/02/using-personal-access-tokens-with-git-and-github.html)
>
> 1. **Get Token**
>
>    The first step in using tokens is to generate a token from the
>    GitHub website
> 2. **Configure local GIT**
>
>    Once we have a token, we need to configure the local GIT client
>    with a username and email address. On a Linux machine, use the
>    following commands to configure this, replacing the values in the
>    brackets with your username and email.
>
>    ```
>    git config --global user.name ""
>    git config --global user.email ""
>    git config -l
>    ```
> 3. **Clone from GitHub**
>
>    Once GIT is configured, we can begin using it to access GitHub. In
>    this example I perform a `git clone` command to copy a repository to
>    the local computer. When prompted for the username and password, enter
>    your GitHub username and the previously generated token as the
>    password.
> 4. **Configure Credential Caching**
>
>    Lastly, to ensure the local computer remembers the token, we can
>    enable caching of the credentials. This configures the computer to
>    remember the complex token so that we don't have to.
>
>    ```
>    git config --global credential.helper cache
>    ```
>
>    If needed, you can later clear the token from the local computer by
>    running
>
>    ```
>    git config --global --unset credential.helper
>    ```

Comment: Something ate the text-in-angle-brackets, but in any case, note that `user.name` and `user.email` are NOT USED for authentication. Only the credential helper settings here matter for https authentication. (Other than the missing text, there's nothing *wrong* here, I just wanted to emphasize the missing text, and the fact that it's the credential helper setting that goes to the OPs question.)